# How to manually set the class width of histograms in Weka?

Tags: weka

I have an instance with values between 0 and 20 (these are school grades). I want to make a histogram with 21 classes, each representing a single grade. The default histograms in the Weka Explorer use Scott's rule to set the class width and amount of classes, but I cannot find a way to change this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you have *numeric* data for the school grade.  You can use the unsupervised attribute filter `NumericToNominal` to convert the attribute and get your 21 distinct values.

Comment: This is exactly what I did in the end, but I hadn't posted it as an answer yet. Let me give you the tick.